# Establecer limite de tiempo de conexión hacia un web service en android

Tags: android, webservice, url

Necesito establecer un ***limite de tiempo de conexión a un web service*** en android. Si demora mucho en obtener los datos que cancele la conexión y muestre un mensaje al usuario diciendo que la conexión se ha interrumpido por x motivos.

Consumo el servicio de una URL con una json dentro,
este es el código que uso para conectarme:

```
String URL = "http://192.168.101.1/ilex/json.html";
    try {
        String result = "";
        //Accedemos al servicio web y leemos los datos devueltos en foramto  json
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(URL));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new                              InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sBuilder.append(line + "\n");
        }
        result = sBuilder.toString();
        nat = new JSONObject(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes añadirlos a la solicitud mediante `HttpParams` en milisegundos. El `setConnectionTimeout` lanza la excepción si la conexión no se establece en ese tiempo. El `setSoTimeout` lanza la excepción si el servicio web no devuelve los datos antes de ese tiempo.

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 90000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 90000);
httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
```

Answer (score 1):

antes que nada te comento que las clases de Apache

```
org.apache.http.*
```

**estan marcadas como obsoletas**, lo deseable es usar **[HttpURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)**.

Usando `HttpClient`  sería :

```
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 10000); //Timeout 10 segundos
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
```

---

Si decides cambiar a  **[HttpURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)**, puedes usar el método `setConnectTimeout()`:

```
   HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
   connection.setConnectTimeout(10000); //10 segundos
```

Comment: hola @Jorgesys, ya me di cuenta por que las clases deapache salen tachadas, me gustaria usar httpURLConnection, me pondrias un ejempo de llamar al servicio con lo del tiempo limite puesto y que el resultado sea en una cadena String para convertirlo a JsonObjetc, espero q no sea mucha molestia, pudera buscar en internet un ejemplo pero estoy en Cuba y aki y internet es complicado, garcias de antemano...

Comment: @FelixAMarreroPentón claro que si, revisa lo que esta dentro del método doInBackground del ejemplo mostrado aquí: http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/01/android-httpurlconnection/ Trata de realizarlo tu mismo y si tienes dudas puedes preguntar nuevamente

Comment: todo ok, ya cambie el metodo y todo funciono bien, con limete de tiempo incluido y todo,... peor no se si te has dado cuenta que soy el mismo que pregunto sobre la conversion de los datos del web service a utf-8, todabia no he podido resolver ese problema, le pase el URLEncoder.encode(cadena, "UTF-8"); y el resultado fue de "Felix A. Marrero Pentón"  a  "Felix+A.+Marrero+Pent%EF%BF%BDn"

Comment: Ok recuerdo una pregunta sobre eso, recuerdo te sugerí una solución pero pensé ya se había solucionado, ahora reviso. Si te sirve esta respuesta marcala como correcta.

Comment: ha otra cosa, si puse un tiempo limite de coneccion de urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000); como pongo la condicion de que si se pasa de ese tiempo aga x cosa